# How do I use conditional compilation with `cfg` and Cargo?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I want to conditionally compile my source code using `cfg` with Cargo,
after Googling for a while,
it seems that the solution is to use `cargo --features`.

http://doc.crates.io/manifest.html

I tried adding a few

```
#[cfg(feature = "foo")]
```

in the source code and

```
cargo build --features foo
```

, but it says

```
Package `xxx v0.0.1 (file:///C:/yyy/xxx)` does not have these features: `foo`
```

How can I let cargo identify the features? Do I have to add something in `Cargo.toml`?

Here's the version of `rustc` and `cargo` I am using:

```
C:\>rustc --version
rustc 0.13.0-nightly (42deaa5e4 2014-12-16 17:51:23 +0000)

C:\>cargo --version
cargo 0.0.1-pre-nightly (5af754d 2014-12-18 01:50:48 +0000)
```

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You have to introduce the existing features in your `Cargo.toml`.

I was able to conditionally compile by doing the following:

- In `Cargo.toml`, create a `features` section and introduce a certain feature name:

  ```
  [features]

  customfeature = [] # feature has no explicit dependencies
  ```

  If you want your feature to have specific dependencies check [the examples in the documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/features.html).
- In your code, use `#[cfg(feature="customfeature")]`
- Run `cargo build --features customfeature`

Since your steps 2 & 3 seem to be fine, there must probably be a problem with your `Cargo.toml`.

Comment: is it possible to test for feature in "if"? Thanks.

Comment: @BulatM. Yes, you can use `if cfg!(feature = "customfeature") { ... }`

Answer (score 12):

As stated in other answers, you can use `features` for this. I would like to add that features do not only allow you to conditionally compile parts of your code but also to conditionally include dependencies that may be part of that code.  Consider the following snippets:

You can activate the conditional code using a feature flag as already described in other anwsers:

```
cargo build --features customfeature
```

You need to mark your conditional code to exist only when your `customfeature` is enabled:

```
#[cfg(feature = "customfeature")]
fn my_func() {
    my_optional_dependency::do_something(); 
}

// This includes dependencies only when customfeature is enabled
#[cfg(feature = "customfeature")] 
extern crate my_optional_dependency;
....

#[cfg(feature = "customfeature")]
use my_optional_dependency::*;
....
```

Your `Cargo.toml` needs to have the following sections:

```
[dependencies.my_optional_dependency]
version = "1.2.3"
optional = true

[features]
customfeature = ["my_optional_dependency"]
```

This allows you to activate certain parts of your code along with their dependencies only if a feature is enabled.

Answer (score 12):

Alternatively, you could create a *cargo configuration file* in your project, by creating a `.cargo` subdir in your project main folder, adding in it a `config.toml` file,
then inserting this section in  `.cargo/config.toml`:

```
[build]
rustflags = "--cfg my_cfg_flag"
```

This will make *cargo* call *rustc* with flags *--cfg my_cfg_flag*

See here for details:
https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/config.html