# How to conditionally compile in Rust

Tags: rust, conditional-compilation

From my experience from C/C++ domains, it would be very useful for a system programing language to be able to compile different codes based on different conditions.

I already know in Rust we got [Attributes](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/attributes.html), attributes like `windows_subsystem` can enable/disable code fragments based on current OS.

What I still can not figure out is, custom situation, like for example in C/C++:

```
#if ENABLE_VIDEO
 // ... code for video only
#endif
```

How can I achive similar in Rust?

Comment: Also see [How do I use conditional compilation with `cfg` and Cargo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27632660/how-do-i-use-conditional-compilation-with-cfg-and-cargo)

Comment: @ljedrz Thanks, very helpful