# How to pass customized arguments from Makefile to Rust codes in Cargo?

Tags: rust, makefile

Now I have a project managed by `Makefile`. That is, `make run` is the entry for the project. `Rust` codes, managed by `Cargo`, is a part of my project.

**What I want to achieve** is to pass some arguments from `Makefile` to `Rust` codes.

I know how to achieve this in `C`:

```
$ gcc --help | grep -- -D
  -D <macro>=<value>      Define <macro> to <value> (or 1 if <value> omitted)
```

So, I can just pass arguments from `make run MYARGUMENT=xxx` and in `Makefile` pass `$(MYARGUMENT)` to `gcc`.

How to achieve it **if I want to pass** `MYARGUMENT` **to command** `cargo run`?

Or, I kind of want a feature like this -- to disable some statements in Rust codes, which could be controlled from Makefile:

```
#ifdef XXX
printf("XXX is define!\n");
#endif
```

Comment: If you just want some conditional compilation, [cargo features](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/features.html) are your best bet. Though you can also [access environment variables](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/macro.env.html). So what is it you want to achieve?

Comment: Are you sure you want to use makefiles and not plain Cargo?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Yes. I am using `cargo` to manage my codes. However, for the full project, `make run xxx=xxx` is the entry. Though I can make some changes in `.cargo/config`.

Comment: Have you checked out [Conditional compilation - The Rust Reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/conditional-compilation.html) and [How do I use conditional compilation with `cfg` and Cargo? - StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27632660/how-do-i-use-conditional-compilation-with-cfg-and-cargo)?

Comment: @Caesar Thanks! `cargo features` is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using gcc, you can use `-D` to specify a predefined macro and then use preprofessor directives to compile some code conditionally as below:

```c
int main(void)
{
#if defined(DEBUG_)
    printf("Debug mode\n");
#endif
}
```

And pass `-D` to tell gcc a predefined macro: `gcc -DDEBUG`.

Using rustc, you can use `cfg` equivalently:

```rust
fn main() {
    #[cfg(DEBUG)]
    {
        println!("Debug mode");
    }
}
```

Then run `rustc --cfg 'DEBUG'` and you get the same result as gcc.

If you want to use cargo instead of use rustc directly, you can see this question: [How do I use conditional compilation with `cfg` and Cargo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27632660/how-do-i-use-conditional-compilation-with-cfg-and-cargo)